# Angular Uib Timepicker timezone issues in chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, datetime

I'm using Uib Timepicker to edit/update data in UI. In backend my SQL database saves time in UTC.

Issue-1) While using chrome

Chrome Browser is converting backend UTC timezone to local(Browser) timezone(EST) to display in UI(which is a good feature).

But when I'm updating time into DB from UI, Uib Timepicker is not converting my EST to UTC. It is directly saving EST(values) in DB.

So, 1) How to make Uib to convert EST to UTC for saving in DB(UI to DB).
    2) How to make Uib not to convert UTC to EST for displaying in UI(DB to UI).

Can someone address my both issues. Thanks!!

P.S: IE is not converting my UTC to EST in UI.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just convert it before you submit the date to your service? Once you have the model from the datetime picker, you can use plain javascript to get the ISO string:

```
var utcPickedDate = $scope.pickedDate.toISOString(); //"2017-02-09T21:33:16.862Z"
```

Or UTC if you prefer:

```
var utcPickedDate = $scope.pickedDate.toUTCString(); //"Thu, 09 Feb 2017 21:33:16 GMT"
```